# link_to paths not linking after adding bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, routes, rake

I have a rails application that is built on the `SAAS` stripe application that is hosted here:

http://railsapps.github.com/rails-recurly-subscription-saas/

I added twitter bootstrap to this and my paths are no longer creating links.

For instance my route file has:

```
resources :users
```

however no users_path is creating a link to the location in my erb files

```
<%= link_to 'Admin', users_path %>
```

Any ideas or additional information i could provide?

**Rake routes:**

```
E:\Sites>rake routes  
            stripe_event        /stripe                        StripeEvent::Engine  
            content_gold GET    /content/gold(.:format)        content#gold  
          content_silver GET    /content/silver(.:format)      content#silver  
        content_platinum GET    /content/platinum(.:format)    content#platinum  
                    root        /                              home#index  
                    root        /                              home#index  
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new  
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create  
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy  
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create  
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new  
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit  
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update  
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        registrations#cancel  
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create  
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new  
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit  
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               registrations#update  
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               registrations#destroy  
             update_plan PUT    /update_plan(.:format)         registrations#update_plan  
             update_card PUT    /update_card(.:format)         registrations#update_card  
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index  
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create  
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new  
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit  
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show  
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update  
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
```

Comment: Could you add the `rake routes` to the question?

Comment: Are you saying your users_path is blank? Or is the result of your `<%= link_to 'Admin', users_path %>` empty?

Comment: In this case the 'Admin' text would appear but it would not be a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be caused by bad references to images that occured when i added an asset/images directory from the wrapbootstrap template.

I added this line to my application.rb file below the config.assets.enabled=true

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "images")
```

To get my images to show up after this I had to change them to be in rails format, so background:  img(..) became

```
background: image-url('images/social_icons.png')
```